# Render partial from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, partial

I have a page composed by several partials (3). 
One of them is a forum and when a user submit that forum, rails calls a create of a controller. After the object is created, I have to render the same page.
How is possible from the controller to recall directly the page with the partials already embedded ? Is it possible to specify manually the partial I want in the controller (I don't care if I violate the MVC paradigm).

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding something like this to your application controller (this code is from authlogic gem):

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

Then, in the controller that renders the 3 partials, call `store_location`. Then, in the controller that creates the forum post, call `redirect_back_or_default`.

Hope this helps, 
- Dave

Comment: Tnx, I'm going to try, does the parameter request.request_uri store the partials too or just the url ?